# Sorting conversations with belongs_to/has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

i have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations
end


class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

So there are Posts, and each post can have many conversations. In each conversation are many messages. So far so good.

Now i wanna display an overview of all conversations a user has. It seems i can't get it to work the way i want:

Get all conversations the current user has (`current_user.conversations`) group all conversations according to the Post ID they `belong_to` and rank this groups by date -> The group (of conversations) with the newest message should appear on top. Here is a screenshot of what i have so far.
[image: Sorting conversations]

All covnerations should be grouped by Posts they belong to at every times. If any conversation has a new message in it, the whole group of conversations should move to the top of the view, not only the conversation with the new message. That's what i can't get to work.

The screenshot above was made with the following code:

```
current_user.conversations.includes(:messages, post: :user).order("posts.id DESC, messages.created_at DESC").to_a.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the conversations are grouped by their post id. But the second group should appear above the first group, because the conversation in the second group has the latest message in it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: because you ordered by the `posts.id` first, `posts.id DESC, messages.created_at DESC`

Comment: @lusketeer ordering by `messages.created_at` first destroys the grouping by `post.id` - that's the actual problem. Let's say someone sends a new message in a particular conversation -> then this particular conversation is ranked to the top. But all other conversations (belonging to the same post) stay at the same position. What i want to achieve is, that all conversations, belonging to the same post, are ranked to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your way doesn't work, is just like what @lusketeer commented under the question:

```
because you ordered by `posts.id` first
```

The solution should be grouping the posts first, then load conversations and messages and order by message timestamp:

```
# Add the association between user and post
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :participated_posts, through: :conversation, class: "Post"
  ...
end

current_user.participated_posts.includes(conversations: [:messages, :user]).order("messages.created_at DESC")
```